# Quering database upon combo box selection

Tags: html, mysql

I have this combo box, to select a day a given flight in this case operates on.

```
            <select style="border:1px solid #DCDCDC; color:#003663; font-size:11px;" class="search" name="day" id="day">
                <option value="0">Sunday</option>
                <option value="1">Monday</option>
                <option value="2">Tuesday</option>
                <option value="3">Wednesday</option>
                <option value="4">Thursday</option>
                <option value="5">Friday</option>
                <option value="6">Saturday</option>
            </select>
```

The table we'll be looking for information is called db_schedules. The table structure contains a column called `daysofweek`. 0123456 specify days, 0 being a Sunday, 1-6 Monday-Saturday. Each record has a specified `daysofweek` value i.e schedule 3 is enabled in searches on days 346.

Based on the above, how do I query the database for a search based upon the selected option from the combo box?

Comment: Write a stored procedure or use linq that takes in the parameter dayofweek. the actual query is something like:SELECT *
FROM db_schedule
WHERE daysofweek = dayofweek

Don't use * put what info you actual want back(I just don't know your fields)
daysoftheweek is the parameter passed by the code to the store procedure

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It's not clear, from the question, the datatype of column `daysofweek`, whether that's a varchar and you're storing a string that indicates a set of days, (e.g a value of '1235'  representings Mon, Tue, Wed and Fri), or whether that's an integer column, and you have multiple rows, one for each day.

If it's a VARCHAR column,  to search for days 3, 4 and 6, if you want any db_schedule row that matches any of those days:

```
SELECT ... 
 FROM db_schedule d
WHERE (  d.daysofweek LIKE '%3%' 
      OR d.daysofweek LIKE '%4%'  
      OR d.daysofweek LIKE '%6%'
      )
```

To get a match on all the days, the `AND` those predicates rather than `OR` them

```
SELECT ... 
 FROM db_schedule d
WHERE (   d.daysofweek LIKE '%3%'
      AND d.daysofweek LIKE '%4%'  
      AND d.daysofweek LIKE '%6%'
      )
```

A `REGEXP` could be used in place of the `LIKE`. In the case of an "OR" conditions, e.g. to find matches on '3','4' or '6':

```
 WHERE d.daysofweek REGEXP '[346]'
```

An `INSTR` function would also work:

```
 WHERE (  INSTR(d.daysofweek,'3') 
       OR INSTR(d.daysofweek,'4')  
       OR INSTR(d.daysofweek,'6')
       )
```

Without more detailed information about the exact problem you are facing, it's really not productive to suggest other solutions.

But we might point out that there might be more appropriate datatypes for storing `daysofweek`, the MySQL `SET` datatype would seem to fit the bill.

---

Followup:

If days of week is stored as a VARCHAR(7), and you want to pass in arguments of 'Tuesday', 'Wednesday' and 'Friday' into a SQL query to perform the search...

I just don't understand why you would go to the bother of translating the value(s) returned from the select dropdown box into a character strings like 'Sunday', 'Monday', etc.

The values being returned (according to your HTML code, they would be "0" thru "7"), and those already "match" the values stored in the database.

Comment: The field is a varchar(7) type, and the default value is 0123456. One question though, I'd like to assign a value to each option, i.e. Monday in the select would search 1 in `daysofweek` column of `db_schedules` table. Would therefore the above code work, and could it be used in a .tpl file?

Comment: I have this `public function findschedule($arricao, $depicao, $airline)   {
        $query` and I've added this to the query `AND phpvms_schedules.daysofweek = ''";` How do I tell it to get the value selected by the user out of the select box?

Comment: you would pass the values from the selectbox into the `findschedule`  function as an argument, just like your other three arguments. (For a multi-select, it's convenient to handle the individual returned values  and populate an array.